# How to find average after sorting month column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-science-experience

I have a challenge in front of me in python.

```
| Growth_rate  | Month |
| ------------ |-------|
|            0 |     1 | 
|           -2 |     1 | 
|          1.2 |     1 | 
|          0.3 |     2 | 
|         -0.1 |     2 | 
|            7 |     2 | 
|            9 |     3 | 
|          4.1 |     3 |
```

Now I want to average the growth rate according to the months in a new columns. Like 1st month the avg would be -0.26 and it should look like below table.

```
| Growth_rate | Month | Mean  |
| ----------- | ----- | ----- |
|           0 |     1 | -0.26 |
|          -2 |     1 | -0.26 |
|         1.2 |     1 | -0.26 |
|         0.3 |     2 |   2.2 |
|        -0.1 |     2 |   2.2 |
|           7 |     2 |   2.2 |
|           9 |     3 |   6.5 |
|         4.1 |     3 |   6.5 |
```

This will calculate the mean growth rate and put it into mean column.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Your question is quite vague, can you show us how you went from the original data to the ideal output data?

Comment: OP has edited the question to show input and expect output

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(df.months).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'Growth_Rate':'mean'}).merge(df,on='months')
Out[59]: 
   months      mean  Growth_Rate
0       1 -0.266667          0.0
1       1 -0.266667         -2.0
2       1 -0.266667          1.2
3       2  2.200000         -0.3
4       2  2.200000         -0.1
5       2  2.200000          7.0
6       3  6.550000          9.0
7       3  6.550000          4.1
```

Comment: Please check the image that i have attached

Comment: @ParthDhir what about the image?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the `pandas` package. If your table is in a  DataFrame `df`

```
In [91]: means = df.groupby('Month').mean().reset_index()
In [92]: means.columns = ['Month', 'Mean']
```

Then join via merge

```
In [93]: pd.merge(df, means, how='outer', on='Month')
Out[93]:
   Growth_rate  Month      Mean
0          0.0      1 -0.266667
1         -2.0      1 -0.266667
2          1.2      1 -0.266667
3          0.3      2  2.400000
4         -0.1      2  2.400000
5          7.0      2  2.400000
6          9.0      3  6.550000
7          4.1      3  6.550000
```

Comment: I want mean of growth rate according to months.

Comment: @ParthDhir I think my solution does sort it by month as you showed in your example

Comment: Please check the image which I have attached.